# python parse string with rules

Tags: python, regex

```
s = '>50&<100'
s2 = '>30'
s3 = '<30'
s4 = '=10'
s5 = '!=10'
s6 = '>2|<5'
```

so my strings should be:

- comparison operator ( < > = != )
  followed by an integer value -> we call it EXPRESSION
- optional logical operator ( | & )
  followed by an EXPRESSION

What's the best way to:

a. validate the input string
b parse it so I can create the expression in valid python

P.S
I can thing of a regex solution. I was thinking something like creating a grammar and parse it to a tree.

Answer (score 1):

you can create you `regex` by following , and as says in comment if you want a common solution you need this patterns :

```
s = '>\d+&<\d+'
s2 = '>\d+'
s3 = '<\d+'
s4 = '=\d+'
s5 = '!=\d+'
s6 = '>\d+|<\d+'

string_list=[s,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6]
rx = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, string_list)))
```

and then use a proper `re` function (for example : `rx.match(string)`)!

> **re.escape(string)**
>       Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

Comment: Wont this only match the exact examples he gave, rather than applying the generic rules he wants to use?

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex

```
^(<|>|!=|=)\d+([&|](<|>|!=|=)\d+)*
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/fX5lC2/2